# Python - Import modules

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I have a python script in my cgi-bin and it works, its just a simple hello world script. And now I want to import some modules like MySqldb and such, and I have them installed in python, as I can run the script from he ssh (terminal) but I cant run it on in the cgi-bin. I get an error that says this

```
 /var/www/cgi-bin/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py in ()
 /var/www/cgi-bin/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py in ()
 /var/www/cgi-bin/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py in __bootstrap__()
 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py in resource_filename(self=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>, package_or_requirement='_mysql', resource_name='_mysql.so')
```

And this

```
class 'pkg_resources.ExtractionError'>: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg cache: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/httpd/.python-eggs' The Python egg cache directory is currently set to: /usr/share/httpd/.python-eggs Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? You can change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to point to an accessible directory. 
      args = ("Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n",) 
      cache_path = '/usr/share/httpd/.python-eggs' 
      manager = <pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance> 
      message = "Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n" 
      original_error = OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

So how can I import/install the module there?

Thanks

Comment: "*I cant run it on in the cgi-bin*" -- What happens when you try? Do you get an error message? A log message? Does smoke come out of your computer?

Comment: @Robᵩ haha, sorry about that how are you supposed to help me if I dont tell you whats wrong, see edit. I think I need to give it the path to module or something but Im not sure how to do that?